# C Child process creation

Tags: c, process, fork, pid, child-process

I am writing a program that creates a two processes directly from the parent. My expected output looks like

```
Main programs process ID: 2834
Child 2 (ID: 2836) Start Sequence at: 23
Child 1 (ID: 2835) Start Sequence at: 20
```

My actual output is

```
Main programs process ID: 2834
Child 2 (ID: 2834) Start Sequence at: 23
Child 1 (ID: 2835) Start Sequence at: 20
```

My code is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pid_t pid;
   int n;

    if (argc == 1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./a.out <starting value>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    int p_pid;
    p_pid = getpid();

    printf("Main programs process ID: %d\n", p_pid); 

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
       int c1;
       c1 = getpid();
       printf("Child 1 (ID: %d) Start Sequence at: %d\n", c1, n);
    }

    if(pid != 0){
       int c2;
       c2 = getpid();
       printf("Child 2 (ID: %d) Start Sequence at: %d\n", c2, n+3);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the correct child 1 process but not the correct child 2 process. What am I doing wrong or how can I fix this issue?

Comment: the code only has one call to `fork()` so only one child is created.

Comment: NOTE: the function: `fork()` has three(3) kinds of return values.  The posted code is only checking the `==0` return and then assuming that no error occurred. That is a very bad programming practice to fail to check for errors.

Comment: the main process (the parent) should not return until all the children have exited.  Therefore, the parent should call `wait()` or better `waitpid()` for each child before the parent exits.

Comment: Strongly suggest (To make it much easier to keep track of which process is executing which code) that each child code block have a call to `exit()` as its' last code statement.

Comment: what if the executable is not named `a.out`?  suggest this line: `fprintf(stderr,"Usage: ./a.out <starting value>\n");` be replaced with: `fprintf(stderr,"Usage: %s <starting value>\n", argv[0]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fork()` doesn't create 2 new processes. It spawns 1 child from the main process. It returns 0 inside the child process and the PID of the child if you're in the parent.

So in your code, when you think you're in child 2 - that's still the parent. You'll need to call `fork()` again but only inside the parent process.

Comment: please see my comments on the question as to other problems with the posted code